# Unity shadows ignoring shader's transparency but only in build

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, shadow

I've made a custom shader that adds a pass to the surface shader to achieve an outline around the object.  The object is a quad with the characters sprite on it to achieve a 2d character in a 3d game.  The object should be casting a shadow in the same shape as its sprite.

In the editor's play mode the shadows work perfectly:
[image: 2D character casting a shadow that matches its 2d shape]

However when I build the game in either windows or android platform the shadows completely ignore the object's transparency and only show the shadow of the quad.
[image: 2D character casting a rectangular shadow]

I'm not sure if the problem is caused by my shader or something in the settings.  I've reset the quality settings to the default values and still have the problem even when it is set to ultra quality.  The only light in the scene is a directional light with soft shadows turned on.

This is the code in my shader.

```
Shader "Custom/MultiPassOutlineShader" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
        _OutlineColor ("Outline Color",Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _OutlineThickness ("Outline Thickness",float) = 0.05
    }
    SubShader {

        Tags {"RenderType"="Transparent" "Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True"}
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            ZWrite Off
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag alpha
            // make fog work
            #pragma multi_compile_fog

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;

            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            float _OutlineThickness;
            fixed4 _OutlineColor;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                v.vertex = normalize(v.vertex) * _OutlineThickness + v.vertex;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {

                UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, col);
                fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, i.uv);
                fixed4 col = _OutlineColor;
                col.a *= c.a;
                clip(c.a-0.1);
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }

        ZWrite On
        Blend Off
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows alpha
        #pragma target 3.0

        sampler2D _MainTex;

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        half _Glossiness;
        half _Metallic;
        fixed4 _Color;

        // Add instancing support for this shader. You need to check 'Enable Instancing' on materials that use the shader.
        // See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html for more information about instancing.
         #pragma instancing_options assumeuniformscaling
        UNITY_INSTANCING_CBUFFER_START(Props)
            // put more per-instance properties here
        UNITY_INSTANCING_CBUFFER_END

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
            fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
            clip(c.a - 0.9);
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;
            o.Metallic = _Metallic;
            o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
            o.Alpha = c.a;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Standard"
}
```

Comment: Go to File->BuildSettings->PlayerSettings->OtherSettings->Rendering, and check if you have Static Batching, etc enabled.

Comment: Static Batching and Dynamic Batching were both checked. I reset the player settings to the defaults and tried each combination of these two checkboxes.  Nothing has changed.  I feel like the problem may have something to do with the Fallback statement in my shader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding a shadow casting pass.  (for some reason unity has no documentation on these.)  I also changed the fallback to "VertexLit" but I don't know if that had any effect.  I still don't know why the shadow shapes were different in the editor than in the build though.

```
    //From https://answers.unity.com/questions/1003169/shadow-caster-shader.html
    Pass{ 
        Name "ShadowCaster"
        Tags { "LightMode" = "ShadowCaster" }

        Fog {Mode Off}
        ZWrite On ZTest Less Cull Off
        Offset 1, 1

        CGPROGRAM

        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
        #pragma multi_compile_shadowcaster
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        sampler2D _MainTex;

        struct v2f
        {
            V2F_SHADOW_CASTER; 
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD1;
        };


        v2f vert(appdata_full v )
        {
            v2f o;
            o.uv = v.texcoord;
            TRANSFER_SHADOW_CASTER(o)

        return o;
        }

        float4 frag( v2f i ) : COLOR
        {
            fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, i.uv);
            clip(c.a - 0.9);
            SHADOW_CASTER_FRAGMENT(i)
        }
        ENDCG
    }
```